# Please synomise (or delete) [blood-and-smoke] with [vampire-the-requiem-2e]

Tags: support, tags

The book/line nWoD: Blood and Smoke a styx chronicle 
[is set to recieve a new name and cover (and no other major changed),
and be rerelease as Vampire the Requiem 2nd edition](http://theonyxpath.com/the-world-of-darkness-second-edition/)

The only user of [vtr-blood-and-smoke](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vtr-blood-and-smoke),
recently edited his question to use [vampire-requiem-2](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-requiem-2) (a new tag).

The options now are to:

- copy the tag wiki across and delete the old tag, or let the tag delete itself when X months go buy without questions.
- or to create a synonym (but fix the tag to be [vampire-the-requiem-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-the-requiem-2e))

Possibly creating a synonym is unnecessary, and the wiki should just be moved.
I think in this case it is more likely to be necessary since the book has actually been released under 2 titles.

Comment: as of this weekend Blood and Smoke has been removed from DriveThru, if you have purchased it you'll notice you now have Vampire the Requiem 2e in your library. Can we please create [tag:vampire-requiem-2e] and synomise it with [tag:blood-and-smoke]. Per above, the canonical tag should be the 2e one

Comment: @xenoterracide There are all of seven questions tagged [tag:blood-and-smoke].  Wouldn't it be faster to just remove those and add the desired tag?

Comment: @C.Ross I thought we were not wanting to do that previously to preserve tag subscribers and for sure get the synonym.

Comment: @C.Ross oh, and during the holy war discussions over the tags, I got yelled at for doing that, so I didn't do that this time.

Comment: @xenoterracide You were asked to not change lots of tags without discussion. The "lots" and "without discussion" was the problem then. The discussion has been had now though, and making it happen is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or “zombie”) tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/152515) on meta:

> Tags not associated with any question are automatically destroyed at 03:00 UTC every day.

It's currently ~23:48Z. This tag is going to be deleted in about three hours. (It doesn't take months.)

Comment: Ok, I am going to proactively copy the tag wiki over and update the link in the other tag wikis

Comment: I thought that was turned off for RPG.SE?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I don't think so. Maybe you're thinking of [Retaining lonely system tags](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/2726/1204) and its kinda-resolution [Save our system tags](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3067/1204)?

Comment: I think I am! But even so, we still have lots of zombie tags if you go to the last pages of our tag list. It's possible I just don't understand something about the process though.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Those are synonyms of other tags, it's a weird way of handling things but they stick around like that.

Comment: Aha, that's it! Thanks, TIL. :)

Comment: downvoting because this answer is out of date, and new action is needed

Comment: @xenoterracide then the question should be updated with the new situation, or the dupe closure reversed

Answer (score 2):

Relatedly, do we want the tag to instead be [vampire-requiem-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-requiem-2e) or the like?

Comment: Are WoD communities using "2e" at all?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I daresay nothing's being done as a community yet, since we haven't seen what the new Onyx Path trade dress is going to be. Once the covers start coming out, you'll see consensus.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Following up on this: the new trade dress says "Vampire: the Requiem - Second Edition," so I think 2E is just fine.