# Blood and Smoke to Vampire the Requiem 2e

Tags: support, tags, world-of-darkness

This is a follow up to this

[Please synomise (or delete) [blood-and-smoke] with [vampire-the-requiem-2e]](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4909/please-synomise-or-delete-blood-and-smoke-with-vampire-the-reqium-2)

can we please ,migrate synomise the [blood-and-smoke](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blood-and-smoke) to (I believe that's the tag suggested by previous threads) [vampire-the-requiem-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-the-requiem-2e)

as of a little over a week ago Blood & Smoke is no longer available for purchase, and those of us who did received our courtesy downloads of 2nd edition. [As of this past monday the status was](http://theonyxpath.com/the-whatchamacallit-with-the-blurbs-and-blasts-monday-meeting-notes/)

> VTR II –  Found formatting errors in the Index of the PoD versions, so not going up for sale Weds, hopefully next Weds.

It's worth noting that [I have had to correct tags](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51931/1015) recently from [vampire-the-requiem](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-the-requiem) to [blood-and-smoke](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blood-and-smoke) and from [new-world-of-darkness-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-world-of-darkness-2e) to [nwod-god-machine](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nwod-god-machine) so this stuff is getting confusing not being in place

Comment: @Tritium the syntax you're after is `[meta-tag:world-of-darkness]`

Comment: @doppelgreener You caught that quickly, because I deleted instantly.  But yes, that is what I was going for.

Comment: I still do not see the point in indicating edition twice.  If you are using nWoD 2e and tag for vampire the requiem, is it not assumed you are using 2e of vampire?

Comment: @Tritium21 you shouldn't have to have 2 tags ever, only one tag is required, others are just to draw attention. Also as seen with the edit history on the linked question, what edition it was through many edits was almost lost. There's also the chance of people playing a 1e game with 2e rules for editions that aren't out yet. And if you follow the B&S tags you'll notice some have both things tagged because they're about the differences between the 2 editions

Comment: Also we've had a whole slew of arguments about that, the decision was to not have vtr2 until it was out, because it wasn't yet, well, now it's in a transitionary where it depends on who you are and B&S is now unavailable.

Comment: I'm not sure that UN-availability should influence tags; we've got people playing games that have been out of print for decades.

Comment: @BESW the point is more that 2e is in release, and those of us that purchased B&S already have it.

Comment: syn and Burn B&S + VTR2e to vampire-the-requiem, Syn  and burn god-machine to new-world-of-darkness-2e, syn & burn new-world-of-darkness to new-world-of-darkness-1e.  that solves it.  The way the community is trying to use the tags is getting edited into confusion anyways, so all emergence is lost

Comment: @Tritium21 oh for the love of... we already discussed that, I gotta go to work, but will someone please link the umteen arguments on here about that into this question. I don't feel like having them again, I'm just saying that 2e is being published (again, available to existing owners of B&S) and that we said we'd migrate when it happened for realz.

Comment: [Tagging scheme is here](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4933/clean-up-tagging-for-world-of-darkness-related-questions/4962#4962) and should probably be discussed there (or if a major problem warrants it, open a new meta). This meta is just asking for mod help to quickly implement the plan for [blood-and-smoke] now that the game line warrants implementation of the existing plan.

Comment: I retagged this [support], since it's asking for moderators to take an action. The [discussion] tag may have been misleading, as there is no discussion invited here.

Comment: Please do not open duplicate meta questions, especially when your problem was already answered.

Comment: @C.Ross I flagged that question over a week ago for attention, and received no response

Comment: @C.Ross and the answer was based on when the problem was new and before we decided on the [tag:blood-and-smoke] until the rebrand came out, during the holy wars over these tags.

Comment: @xenoterracide Currently only 7 questions have [blood-and-smoke]. I'm unclear on what the mod response to the request is, but we could just go ahead and manually implement the retag and make the confusion over this moot. The synonyming can be taken care of later (or via the normal propose-vote process).